# Is it possible to have automatic failover of a windows service without windows clustering?

Tags: high-availability, failover, cluster, service

Due to a partial failure of our SAN we have switched our message queuing (Active MQ) from using network storage to using local storage.  Because the secondary server is no longer sharing the same storage location as the primary, the service is shut down and must be manually started if the primary fails.

The services are running on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition.  Is there any way to automatically start the service on the secondary server if the primary fails?  Windows clustering appears to require Enterprise Edition and I am unable to upgrade the servers in the short term.

Answer (score 2):

Windows services have actions that can be configured to run a script on failure. Theoretically, you could write a script that starts the service on the other machine. However, this doesn't help if the whole machine dies.

Shared storage with iscsi is ridiculously easy to set up on any spare hardware you might have hanging around that you can install Linux or free bsd on. Even windows does iscsi sharing. Instead of reinventing the wheel, just do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are many service monitoring apps like [PA Server Monitor](http://www.poweradmin.com/servermonitor), [FrameFlow](http://www.frameflow.com) and [SolarWinds Orion](http://www.solarwinds.com) among others that could easily monitor a service, and if it fails, start a different service.